# docker - Move files from one volume bind to another

Tags: docker

I have some docker containers with volumes bound to directories on the host, all on the same hard drive.
But from example when I run `mv /input/test /output/test`, where input and output are both bolumes bound to directories on the same hard drive, it takes forever as if they were on different drives. I can see huge spikes of read / write on my hard drive too.

Is there a way to have `mv` behave in docker as if it was running on the host (maybe some option to docker run), actually moving the file instead of copying then deleting the original ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both directories in a single volume.

From the perspective of the container the two volumes are distinct filesystems. It must copy from one to the other. There is no way to know that they have the same backing store.

Comment: Thanks, I did that. Not ideal, since this is all going through the same kernel I would have expected it to be smart enough to not do a full copy, but oh well

Comment: @Ulrar Such knowledge would violate the security that the mount namespace provides.

Comment: Right, that's fine, I don't mind. Would have been a nice option to have with the dozens of other capabilities